# creating a custom enumerate

Tags: enumerate

I would like to make a variant of enumerate called steps where if I do something like

```
\begin{steps}

\item This is step 1

\item This is step 2

\end{steps}
```

The output would be like

Step 1. This is step 1

Step 2. This is step 2

How would I go about something like this? What if I wanted these labels in bold or a different color.

Finally in this environment if I wanted to be able to skip a step I know for enumerate it would be \setcounter{enumi}{}, but what would it be for this?

Comment: Have a look at the enumitem package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `enumitem` manual, section 7 already shows, how to make a `steps` environment. Here with some adaption to print the labels you want:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{steps}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[steps,1]{label=Step \arabic{*}.}

\begin{document}
\begin{steps}
\item This is step 1
\item This is step 2
\end{steps}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To setup more levels, change the last argument of `\newlist` and do additional `\setlist`. See the `enumitem` manual for more information.

BTW: `\stepcounter` has only one argument, so `\stepcounter{enumi}` is enough to jump over one step (at level 1). You don't need an extra empty group after it.